# UNUserNotifications method `requestAuthorization` doesn't show dialogue on macOS Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, unusernotificationcenter, usernotifications, mac-catalyst

We are successfully using the Push Notifications in various builds, but on Mac Catalyst `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` doesn't show popup so as a result the user doesn't know that notifications should be turned on if he wishes.

The iOS/iPadOS version shows them properly. If notifications are enabled manually they work without problems.

Affected OSs: 10.15-10.15.3 with Xcode 11-11.3.1

Comment: Seems I can't get popup dialog once it shown at least on time. Don't know how to `reset` app settings like it is possible by removing App on iOS simulator :0